# how to use phantomjs 2.0 in AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, phantomjs

i downloaed phantomjs binary from 
https://github.com/bprodoehl/phantomjs/releases/ , test fine on my localhost.

package and create aws lambda function

```
exports.handler = function (event, context) {
    var path = require("path");
    var Process = require("child_process");

    Process.exec(path.join(__dirname,"./bin/phantomjs")+" --version", function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
            context.fail(err.stack);
        } else {
            context.succeed(data);
        }

    })
}
```

but when test in lambda , always got

```
{"errorMessage":"Error: Command failed: /bin/sh: /var/task/bin/phantomjs: Permission denied

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:658:15)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:979:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:466:12)"}
```

anybody has any idea ?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not the answer you want, but it's not such a good idea to use Lambda for "big binary packages" like this.  I believe it is technically possible to do what you want, but keep in mind that PhantomJs has a pretty huge startup cost (memory+cpu) and so your lambda bill will probably be quite high for the value you are getting.

I suggest you see if https://PhantomJsCloud.com can meet your needs in this situation.   (Disclosure: I wrote it)

If you continue down the Lambda path, try following this resource: https://github.com/justengland/phantom-lambda-template